# How to identify which bundle is in execution in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

Lets say I have three bundles in my Symfony 2 project namely AcmeBundle, LibraryBundle and LibraryAppBundle. Is there any mechanism to identify which bundle is in execution. Or in other words, the request is issued for which bundle?

Comment: you see in the log which route matches from there on you could log yourself

Comment: @johnSmith, I am new to Symfony2, can you please explain me with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could take a look at which route matches like

```
 tail -f app/logs/dev.log | grep "Matched route"
```

then you make your request and you see which route matches, for example:

```
"standard_homepage" (parameters: "_controller":"standard\StandardBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction", "path":"", "_route": "standard_homepage")
```

you see in the controller path, which bundle is called, and you can inspect the action/method for calls to other bundles, you can also use loggin for trace the way your request goes

in controller you can get the logger like :

```
$logger = $this->get("logger");
```

and you can log an info message like :

```
$logger->info("my log message")
```

update:

in Controller you can get bundle name like :

```
echo $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_template')->get('bundle');
```

you can get the controlelr name like:

```
echo $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_template')->get('controller');
```

you can get the action like:

```
echo $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_template')->get('action');
```

above seems to work only with @View annotations  like that you can get the controller name and extract the bundle name of it

```
$this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
But let me be more clear what I want to do. Let say I have one another bundle named ExceptionBundle. In this bundle, I have a listener for Exception handling. In this listener, I want to find out that the exception has been occured on which bundle's request (i.e. from AcmeBundle or LibraryBundle or LibraryAppBundle) and based on that I will load my custom view from that particular bundle.
So I think the code you have posted will not help me.